# PROBLEMA COM AJAX JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Arquivo IMG_TROCAR.PHP
codigo

```
<?php
    include_once('config/config.php');
    $ligacao = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$baseDado;host=$host", $user, $pass);

    $id = $_POST['id_user'];

    $mudarAvatar = $_FILES['img_avatar'];

    if($mudarAvatar['name'] == ""){
        //header('Location:perfil.php?ref=configuracao');
       echo '<p>avatar esta fazio</p>';
        exit;
    }else if($mudarAvatar['name']){
        //faz a troca de foto do avatar no banco de dado
        $atualizarAvatar = $ligacao->prepare("UPDATE users SET avatar = ? WHERE id_user = ?");
        $atualizarAvatar->bindParam(1, $mudarAvatar['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $atualizarAvatar->bindParam(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $atualizarAvatar->execute();

        $location = "avatar/";

        move_uploaded_file($mudarAvatar['tmp_name'], $location.$mudarAvatar['name']);

        //header('Location:perfil.php?ref=configuracao');
    }

        //busca a informação do usuario
        $sql = "SELECT avatar, username, email_user FROM users WHERE id_user = :id";
        $consulta = $ligacao->prepare($sql);
        $consulta->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $consulta->execute();
        $result[] = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

       $ligacao = null;

?>
```

tenho um arquivo JSON img_trocar.php que so retorna uma unica linha de um contato

```
[
    {
        "avatar": "IMG_20180208_171358_956.jpg",
        "username": "rafaelshembek",
        "email_user": "rafaelshembek@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

ate aqui tudo bem
Agora o problema é aqui nesse codigo,

```
function uploadFoto(){
    var img = '';
    var location = $('.r_f_p');//local onde vai aparece as informações do usuario
    $.getJSON('img_trocar.php')
    var obj = JSON.parse(dado)
    .always(function(dado){
        img += '<p>' + dado[0].username + '</p>';
        img += '<img src="avatar/'+dado[0].avatar+'">';

    });
    location.html(img);
}
```

O problema é que não aparece as informações na pagina para o usuario no console fala que o dado not is defined alguem tem uma solução para isso

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você não nada como parâmetro para a rotina php, mas dela recebe informações.

A primeira sugestão, portanto, é garantir que o "dado" seja devolvido pela rotina php propriamente convertido no formato JSON. Isso pode ser feito com o código abaixo:

```
echo json_encode($dado);
```

Onde $dado é a variável que contém:

[ { "avatar": "IMG_20180208_171358_956.jpg", "username": "rafaelshembek", "email_user": "rafaelshembek@gmail.com" } ]

Para complementar, caso não se importe em usar JQuery, sugiro que modifique um pouco seu código para fazer a chamada ajax conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
var img = '';
var location = $('.r_f_p');//local onde vai aparece as informações do usuario
var url = "img_trocar.php";

$.ajax({
    context : this,
    type    : "POST", 
    url     :url, 
    data    : pack, 
    dataType: "json", 
    encode  : true,
})
.done(function(dado){
    img += '<p>' + dado[0].username + '</p>';
    img += '<img src="avatar/'+dado[0].avatar+'">';
})
.fail(function(dado){   
    e_OnError(data);
});
```

Assim você tem a garantia que o retorno será recebido adequadamente se nenhum outro erro ocorrer durante o processo.

Comment: eu fiz seu exemplo so que no console fala que pack is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro está aqui

```
$.getJSON('img_trocar.php')
var obj = JSON.parse(dado)
```

Você faz um request para receber o json, mas não faz nada com ele, depois você chama parse esperando `dado` que não existe em nenhum lugar... Ainda assim `$.getJSON()` já um short hand para uma requisção ajax que recebe um json, não há nenhuma necessidade do `JSON.parse(dado)`. E por último, não crie uma variável chamada `img` que na verdade irá representar um bloco de html.

Segue abaixo um exemplo com a sua função `uploadFoto()` alterada e renomeada para `loadContato()`, por que é isso que o método faz.

```
function loadContato() {
  var location = $('.r_f_p');
  //Se o arquivo img_trocar.php está na raiz do seu site, coloque a "/" 
  //no início, caso contrário, indique o caminho correto para a sua localização. 
  $.getJSON('/img_trocar.php', function(dado){
      var html = '';           
      html += '<p>' + dado[0].username + '</p>';
      html += '<img src="avatar/' + dado[0].avatar + '">';
      location.html(html);
  });  
}
```

Comment: eu fiz seu exemplo mais no DOM onde esta a div com class="r_f_p" não mostra o nome do username nem o avatar nem no console não retorna nada

Comment: O caminho para img_trocar está certo do ponto onde o javascript está sendo executado?

Comment: vou atualizar la encima e por o codigo da pagina img_trocar.php para você ver

Comment: Na verdade importa o caminho dela no seu site

Comment: como a sim faz um exemplo ai pra me ver

Comment: Editei e adicionei o comentário:  Se o arquivo img_trocar.php está na raiz do seu site, coloque a "/" no início, caso contrário, indique o caminho correto para a sua localização.